# How can i remove currency sign on amount before uploading to database?

Tags: php

Before it get's inserted to sql database the currency sign on amount is already removed.

Comment: no code = no answer!. don't be lazy! make an attempt and post the error you get

Comment: Strings don't just contain currency symbols, [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

you can get your string replaced by using str_replace()

```
$string = str_replace( $search_for_sign, $replace_the_sign_with_nothing, $in_your_string );
```

For Example:

```
$string_with_target_sign = "$ value";
$formatted_string = str_replace("$" , "" , $string_with_target_sign);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `substr()`. If the sign is in front of the amount, you just have to set the start value to 1. If the sign is behind the amount, you set the start value to 0 and the length value to the length of the amount.

For example:
Sign in front of amount:
`substr("¥100",1);`
Sign after amount:
`substr("100€",0,3);`

Comment: and what if the sign is before the number?? This is why you do not add code answers when OP has not clarified the requirements. You have enough reputation to ask for more information in the comments. Do that!

Comment: Did you read my answer? I wrote in the second sentence, that if the sign is in front of the amount, you use `substr()`and set the start value to 1. Or do you mean, that I should also add an example for that? I have added that now.